# 7/6 no 3 or 13 no 3, 9, 11; which chord name is more correct (if any)?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

Which name is better, more correct?

C13 is C E G Bb D F A.

If we remove the third, ninth, and eleventh, we get C G A Bb.

Would C13 no 3, 9, 11 be an correct name? I've found that same chord named as C7/6 no 3 (dominant seventh, added sixth, no third).

Which one makes more sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't go with either of the names you suggested. When you use "no" chord notation typically you are changing the intended harmony of a chord to something the chord symbol was not ment to represent.

Let's look at what we have:

```
 C G A Bb
```

I'm assuming the C is the bass note. It would  be a stretch to call this any type of C chord because not only is there no 3rd, but there is also no 2nd or 4th. There is very rarely a chord with an omitted 3rd that is not suspend.(Besides a power chord which this is not.)

If we look at this chord as some kind of A chord it makes much more sense because we can stack the chord in thirds now and have it make sense:

```
A C _ G Bb
```

We still have no 5th, but the 5th is commonly omitted in larger chords.  A to C makes a minor 3rd, the G is a minor 7th and the Bb is a b9. Because the C is in the bass, we will have to notate the chord in slash notation so we get:

```
Am7b9/C
```

Still a lengthy name, but it describes the function of the chord better than C13 no 3, 9, 11 where it is very odd to omit 3 notes in a chord.

Another thing to note is it is typical in a 13th chord to omit the 9th and 11th as they are optional. So the suggested name could be reduced to C13 no 3, but still it is odd to omit a 3rd without some kind of sus.

Answer (score 2):

If we remove the third, ninth and eleventh from C13 we get C G Bb A,

so I guess the most correct term would be  C13 no 3, 9, 11 or just C13 no 3(I think that a C13 chord doesn't necessarily have a 9th or 11th,but I'm not sure).

But C G A Bb would be C6/7 no 3, because the A here is the 6th, not the 13th. It would have to be one octave higher in order to be the 13th.

Answer (score 1):

Given the notes C G A Bb, I would think of it as a Gmadd2 (no5)/C
or taking the notes in the order which would come from C13 removing the third, ninth, and eleventh [C G Bb A] I would think of it as a Gm add9 (no 5)/C.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "correct" way to exactly name this chord using the standard nomenclature.

Comment: Did you mean there's no single correct way, or that the chord cannot be named? A bit more explaining would make the answer more valuable.

Comment: I meant that there's no nomenclature (as far as I know) that names this chord in any useful way, other than simply spelling it out as C G A Bb.  But if I had to name what it sounds like to me, I'd say Cb7 plus 6.  The feeling of b7th chords doesn't really need a third, and the A just sounds to me to be the sixth degree thrown in for a bit of dissonance.  I don't think you can get away with calling that "C 13".  But of course that's just my personal take.  I don't see any point in trying to define the "best" way of describing this chord in a very oversimplified system.

Comment: Must disagree that dom7 chords don't need a 3. 5 can be dispensed with, but not 3 - that tells if it's maj. or min.

Comment: "*I don't see any point in trying to define the "best" way of describing this chord in a very oversimplified system.*" The asker probably sees a point to it, since they went to the trouble to ask. It seems like this answer is really saying, "I don't want to answer this question and I don't think anyone else should either".

Comment: @Tim- we'll just have to agree to disagree.  Whether the third of a chord is major or minor is almost always implied by the scale.  If you have the chord progression, spelled out from below in C major, of cge'g'/Ggd'f'/cgc'e', doesn't the second chord sound like a dom7 to you?

Comment: @ToddWilcox- not at all.  I'm just saying that standard nomenclature doesn't have a really useful name for this chord.  If you think it does, what is it?

Comment: @ScottWallace a third is never implied. Ever hear of a Picardy third? Also how many songs written in C use both Dm7 and D7. It's quite a lot.

Comment: @Dom- I disagree.  Of course there are Picardy thirds and other accidentals, but If a melody is in C major you expect E and not Eb.

Comment: @ScottWallace it's not implied which is my point. The only note that can be implied is a perfect 5th due to its place in the harmonic series. You can't assume notes are there that aren't. There are always the possibility of the harmony drastically changing. In fact, going or borrowing from a parallel key or mode is extremely common. Also remember the harmony dictates what set of notes make the most sense to play at that time regardless of what key you are in.

Comment: @Dom- I suspect we're thinking about different kinds of music.  Sure, in many modern forms of music, there are lots of notes outside the key signature (if there is a key signature), and what you say is true, but for most folk and popular music, you don't expect accidentals.

Comment: I'd just like to add to my answer, which was perhaps not clear: I have nothing against people trying to find a useful notation for this chord.  I just wanted to point out that it's not something where we should agonize about the "correct" notation, because any standard abbreviation such as C 13 is going to have to be ambiguous.

Comment: @ScottWallace, Maybe incorporate your comments into the answer?